# R packages: How to access csv files in data subfolder?

Tags: r

I have successfully written an R package and want to ship it with a specific `csv` file. I placed the file in the `data` and `data-raw` subfolders.

```
read.csv("data/foobar.csv")
```

The above command fails. How can I read the `csv` file?

Comment: use paste0() to combine your base folder and all the csv's which you wish to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-raw` is for storing data alongside a short R script that will do the conversion to R data for the user, and the user will just use the `data()` function.[<sup>[source]</sup>](https://www.davekleinschmidt.com/r-packages/) Alternatively, if you want the raw CSV to be user-accessible, I think you need to use the `extdata` folder, as documented [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data-extdata). Then the user can get the actual path to the file on their system, after package installation, with `system.file("extdata", ..., package = "mypackage")`. Then, finally, they can feed that path to `read.csv()` with whatever options they like.

Comment: `extdata` is what I was looking for. Thank you!